# Bound on Lindblad Jump Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, open-quantum-systems

I am trying to understand the jump operators in the Lindblad equation. Specifically, if there is any condition of boundedness we need to impose on them. I ask this because, as was pointed out in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759398/norm-of-a-jump-operator), there should be no assumption on the norm of the jump operators. But for example in this [review](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/adv/article/10/2/025106/1021638/A-short-introduction-to-the-Lindblad-master), the jump operators live in the space of bounded operators. So is boundedness of the jump operators a necessary condition? In [Preskill's notes](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf), there is a derivation of the Lindbladian in terms of the operator-sum representation which gives some normalization condition that the jump-operator should fulfill in terms of the Kraus operators but I am not sure if this is relevant to my question.